# Android application does not works: "The xx.xx application (xx.xx process) stopped unexpectedly. Try again

Tags: c#, android, .net, monodevelop, xamarin.android

Well, I'm getting started in applications android development, as I'm familiar with C#.NET(and I love it), I decided to use the fantastic `MonoDroid` project. I downloaed and installed,worked fine until now. I created *hello world* application, using `MonoForAndroid_API_8` emulator device, worked fine. 
then I  copied `*.apk` files and installed in my tablet with `android OS 2.2`, but when I run my application,I get the following error:

```
The xx.xx application (xx.xx process) stopped unexpectedly. Try again.
```

how to fix this? Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. I wrote to the support. They answered, gave me this url
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Preparing_Package_for_Android_Marketplace?highlight=android+deploy
But this didn't help. I even signed with my own key.
Also I tried to create project and start it on my HTC Sensation (4.0.3). I got the same problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find information [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log) about how to view the Android logs.

I'll take a guess at what your problem is though, without having seen the logs. Are you using the full version of Mono for Android or the evaluation? The eval doesn't support deploying to an actual device.

If you are on the full version, is the APK from a debug build or release? Debug builds are made to use a shared runtime to make deployments quicker, but it means that the APK doesn't contain everything the app needs to run. Release builds don't use the shared runtime, so the Mono runtime is bundled with the APK.

Comment: I'm using evaluation version and the APK that I copied from debug folder, with it can't I to build application small that run on tablet?

Comment: No, as I mentioned, the evaluation version only supports deploying to the emulator at this time.

Comment: I wasn't aware that a `Debug` version was a light version. After having copied the `Release` APK everything is in place. Thanks.